# How can I populate Array with Ms SQL query results in swift?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, swift

I'm new to writing programs with Xcode. 
I am doing the MS SQL connection successfully, but how can I populate an Array variable with a defined query result. I want to show the string values ​​that I populate to the Array variable on TableView.
I've come up to my code:

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,SQLClientDelegate {
    func error(_ error: String!, code: Int32, severity: Int32) {
        print("\(error!) \(code) \(severity)")
}
    @IBOutlet weak var userListTableView: UITableView!
    var client:SQLClient!
    var uNames: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
//Initially we call the DB data in internal memory.
        strIP = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DBServerIP")!
        strDBName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DBName")!
        strUName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DBUser")!
        strPass = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DBPass")!
}
    @IBAction func btnUserAct(_ sender: Any) {
        client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
        client.delegate = self
        client.connect(strIP,username: strUName,password: strPass,database: strDBName){ success in
            if success {
                self.client.execute("Select UserId from Usertbl order by Id") {
                results in
                    for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                        for row in table {
                            for (columnName, value) in row {
                                print(value)
//Here, UserId data appears successfully in the Xcode Debug area. So connection successful.
//How can I populate these values ​​to the uNames Array variable?
}}}
                    self.client.disconnect()
}}}}}
extension SecondViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return uNames.count
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = uNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}}
```

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial, if your question is How to add a value to array, you can use `append` method of array in Swift. The `value` is of type `AnyObject`, so you must convert to `String`. Try do this:

```
for (columnName, value) in row {
         print(value)

         // First option
         let newVal = value as? String ?? ""
         self.uNames.append(newVal)

         // Second option
         // self.uNames.append(value as! String)


        //Here, UserId data appears successfully in the Xcode Debug area. So connection successful.
        //How can I populate these values ​​to the uNames Array variable?
}
```

Comment: this error note appears: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject)'

Comment: in this time this error note appears: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyObject'

Comment: in first option, that appears: Reference to property 'uNames' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit. recommends Insert 'self.' I fixed it, so self.uNames.append(newVal). in this care no error notes appears, but uNames values does not appears in tableview

Comment: @halilbalcıoğlu Sorry, just add `self.` like the update. If it ins't works, try second option.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLClien seems to return Objective-C classes like NSArray, NSNumber etc hence `value` is of type AnyObject. Assuming that the underlying column is of type int and then `value` is of type `NSNumber` I think you will need to convert it to a String in two steps

```
if let intVal = value as? Int {
    self.uNames.append(String(intVal)
}
```

Comment: it does not work. in first answer , first option works bu I could not make it appear uNames on tableview.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in tableview it is most likely because this is an asynchronous call and you are calling 'reloadData()' on table view (or similar) before the result has come back from server. This is a completely different question but you could try to add `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}` directly after the for loop

Comment: So thank you Joakim. Finally your DispatchQueue code solved my problem. thank you very much.